# Make no rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile

I know this is a recursive question, but I spent two days looking for an answer that fit my problem and I fail constantly.

I am using Eclipse neon 3 and I have imported a project of a stm32 MCU that works perfectly in the computer of a friend, but I try to build the project and it is impossible, I just receive:

> make: *** No rule to make target `D:\Proyectos\ENTROL\H19_SN049\Software\RBP_CPU\Rv00\uC\app\trunk\Project\App\inc/stm32f2xx_conf.h 
>    D:\Proyectos\ENTROL\H19_SN049\Software\RBP_CPU\Rv00\uC\app\trunk\Libraries\STM32F2xx_StdPeriph_Driver\inc/stm32f2xx_adc.h', needed by `Utilities/Third_Party/lwip_v1.3.2/src/api/tcpip.o'.  Stop.

But this headers are include in the path, in `properties->C/C++ build->settings->Cross GCC Compiler-> includes`.

Could anyone give some advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a path issue:

```
D:\Proyectos\ENTROL\H19_SN049\Software\RBP_CPU\Rv00\uC\app\trunk\Project\App\inc/stm32f2xx_conf.h
```

Isn't it:

```
C:\app\trunk\Project\App\inc/stm32f2xx_conf.h
```

Instead?